# How to collect items from a Flow until a particular condition is met?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a `Flow<List<Int?>>` and I want to collect this flow but only until I get a null Int. Then the flow should get cancelled. For example,

```kotlin
val flow = flowOf(
    listOf(1, 2),
    listOf(3, null),
    listOf(4)
)
flow.collectUntilNull {
    println(it)
}
```

The output that I want is:

```
[1, 2]
[3, null]
```

I know there is a function `Flow.takeWhile` but it doesn't emit the value where predicate returns false. In my case I want that one also.

```kotlin
public fun <T> Flow<T>.takeWhile(predicate: suspend (T) -> Boolean): Flow<T> = flow {
    return@flow collectWhile { value ->
        if (predicate(value)) {
            emit(value)
            true
        } else {
            // I want a "emit(value)" here
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Since `collectWhile` is internal I can't use this code. Although I guess I can copy paste that `collectWhile` implementation in my code. But is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`transformWhile`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/transform-while.html) is a more flexible/generalized `takeWhile`.

```
flow
    .transformWhile {
        emit(it)
        myCondition(it)
    }
    .collect {
        println(it)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, one way that I found looks something like:

```kotlin
var b = true
flow.takeWhile {i -> b.also { b = myCondition(i) } }
    .collect {
        println(it)
    }
```

Taking it out as an extension,

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntil(predicate: suspend (T) -> Boolean): Flow<T> {
    var b = true
    return takeWhile { i ->
        b.also { b = predicate(i) }
    }
}

// Usage
flow.takeUntil { myCondition(it) }
    .collect {
 
    }
```

Is there a better way?